# Angular 2 - remove auto save username and password

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a log in form where I have done validations using Angular 2 form validations as below.

```
  <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate class="loginForm">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid}">
      <label class="lbl">*Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control uname" name="username" autofocus [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required
        >
      <div class="alert alert-danger" [hidden]="!f.submitted || (username.touched && username.valid)">User Name is required</div>
    </div>
```

I have used ngModel="model.username" because model is an object in which I will be sending both username and password to backend.

Form, validation is working fine as expected but when a user save the username and password with browser which is auto save, and open the page and click log in button at that time validation is failing and giving error messages. Either I want to remove auto saved details from browser or it should validate true in case data is already there.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is Nothing to do with Angular. Add `autocomplete="off"` attribute on `form` element to disable autocomplete feature provided by browser.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, thanks for the response, I understand that but somehow I want to validate browser saved username and password fields, is there any work around.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the following **property** `autocomplete="new-password"` in input field of `form`

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

If you have password field then add this to password Input field.